# Naming a table in Excel Online

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I'm using Excel Online and, having inserted a table into a spreadsheet, I would like to name the table.  Is this possible in the free online edition and, if so, how?

(I've done various searches, and my current thinking is that this behaviour is only available in Office 365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The Microsoft Office Support have [a topic](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/can-i-change-a-table-name-dc409858-05f6-471a-8ab2-3bf70e3dfd46) refering just that:

> You may see default table names like Table1 and Table2 in your formulas and wonder how to change them to something more meaningful. Unfortunately, you can’t do this in Excel Online because the Table Tools aren’t available.

Comment: If you want to change the name of the table, the only way is to open the workbook in Excel (the app)